# not getting the values in xctest

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, xcode6, xctest

I have declared a method called button state as `-(int)buttonstate;`

In `xctest.m` when I instansiate my viewController and assigning to a int value i I am getting wrong value.

```
-(int) buttonstate {

    if ([searchButton isEnabled]) {
        j = 1;
    }
    else
        j = 0;

    NSLog(@" j value is %d",j);

    return j;
}
```

And in the xctest .m file

```
-(void) testwithoutData {
    myapiViewController  *apiViw = [[myapiViewController alloc]init];


    int kn  = [apiViw buttonstate];

    NSLog(@"the value is %ld",(long)kn);        
}
```

Comment: both methods are in the same view? and you want to pass the state value in other controller?

Comment: if UITextField Contains text then uiButton will enabled and the value will be 1 and i need that j value in xctest.m file i am getting the value as 0 if i run the test before when view is allocated the value is 1 after when i see in (int kn ) it is 0

Comment: you have to enable serachButton in testwithoutData before calling buttonstate to see value 1 when you run test case.

Comment: -(void) textdata
{
    long i = search.text.length;  the value is 1 while i run the app but in testwithoutData it is 0
    
    if (i > 0) {
        searchButton.enabled = YES;
        
    }
    
    else
    {
        searchButton.enabled = NO;
        
    }
    
    
    [self buttonstate];
    
    
}

-(int) buttonstate {
    
    
    
    if ([searchButton isEnabled]) {
        j = 1;
        
        
    }
    
    else
        
        j = 0;
    
    
    NSLog(@" j value is %d",j);
    
    return j;
}     and i have textfield.text = @"300";

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried -

In ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    @public int index;
}
```

In ViewController.m

```
-(void) drawCircle{
    index = 10;
    NSLog(@"the value is %ld",(long)index);
}
```

In ViewControllerTests.m

```
@interface ViewControllerTests : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic,strong) ViewController *vcToTest;
@end

@implementation ViewControllerTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    self.vcToTest = [[ViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void)testExample {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass");
    [self.vcToTest drawCircle];
    NSLog(@"Test is fine. Value %d",self.vcToTest->index);
}
```

Test Result - 
[image]

Comment: When I log index value before calling drawCircle method, I was getting index value 0.

Comment: Please elaborate and how to get 10

Comment: For displaying index value which I set in drawCircle method in ViewControllerTests, I have called that method just before logging index value in testExample. I tried without calling drawCircle but that time I got index value 0. When I debug I found that instance of ViewController getting changed and index value change from 10 to 0. I have called drawCircle method in ViewController viewDidLoad. So my suggestion you call searchbutton enable method first and then try to check the value you want to print. Hope this helps. Check attached test result screenshot.

Comment: i have called the method but still the value is 0 itself

Comment: searchButton enabled yes or no after you called

Comment: If it is enabled then definitely you will get j=1. Use breakpoint and check the flow. Something you are missing here & there.